# How do you limit access to a site by geographical location?

Tags: .htaccess, authorization, ip-address

I need to come up with a way to limit users' access to a page to IP addresses within North Carolina. This has to do with usage rights for some MP3 audio. Are there companies that provide this service or is there a list of IP address ranges for a geographical location? This is on a Unix, JBoss/Seam environment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that is not a good idea (users can use a proxy and bypass this restriction), you can find many services googling for it: http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ip+geolocation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

As far as I know, http://www.maxmind.com is one of the best availableand is used in sites like Sourceforge.

You should implement this restrictions on your application not your server via .htaccess files.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt such a list is available. You can check the register information from the IP address you receive which resolves to the ISP of the user (not very accurate).

But there is always a way to bypass this using proxy services like proxy.org (or google proxy)

Answer (score 1):

use geoip by http://www.maxmind.com/

they have both free and subscription-based services (more precise)

Answer (score 1):

You can try ip2location, and from that list try extracting specific providers in North Carolina. When you check the IP, you can query that list to get the provider and check if that provider in that area or not.

Hope this helps.